# How to reduce the Font of a LWUIT Button text

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-button

I've created 3 LWUIT buttons like below:

```
b1.setText("Tab1");
b1.getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
b2 = new Button();
b2.setText("Tab2");
b2.getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
b3 = new Button();            
b3.setText("Tab3");
b3.getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM,                  Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));

tabs.addTab(b1, tab1List);
tabs.addTab(b2, tab2List);
tabs.addTab(b3, tab3List);
form1.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);
```

My Requirement is to reduce the Font of a Button Text(Tab1,Tab2,Tab3),If i use my above code I'm not able to reduce the font,Can any one any help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know that you can use the LWUIT Resource Editor to do this kind of things?
The Resource Editor will be helpful to customize the style of everything in your interfaces. Take a look on this tutorials:

[Resoruce editor tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwZ98s4iiRU)